# Count the number of checks each method had to perform before fully sorting the array

Tags: java

So I'm writing a program that compares Bubble, Selection, Merge, and Quick Sort.  All 4 methods are given a randomized array of 1000 elements and I count to see how many times it takes a method to perform to fully sort the array.  My question revolves around the placement of my counts.  I know I should look at the Big O complexities for each to get a ballpark estimate of the number but I'm just asking if I put the counts in the right spots.

Bubble Sort:

```
public static int[] bubbleSort(int[] a)
{
    boolean done = false;
    int n = a.length;
    while(done == false)//runs n times
    {
        done = true;
        for(int i = 0; i < n-1; i++)//runs n times
        {
            if(a[i] > a[i+1])//Swap
            {
                bubbleCount++;
                int temp = a[i];
                a[i] = a[i+1];
                a[i+1] = temp;
                done = false;
            }

        }
    }
    return a;
}
```

Selection Sort:

```
public static void selectionSort(int[] a )
{
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length - 1; i++) 
    {
        int pos = i;
        for (int j = i + 1; j < a.length; j++) 
        {
            // increments selection count
            selectionCount++;
            // if a[j] is less than a[pos], set pos to j
            if (a[j] < a[pos]) 
            {
                pos = j;
            }   
        }
        // swaps a[i] and a[pos]
        int temp = a[i];
        a[i] = a[pos];
        a[pos] = temp;
    }
}
```

Merge Sort:

```
public static void mergeSort(int [] a)
{
    //put counter for checks inside method
    int size = a.length;
    if(size < 2)//Halt recursion
    {
        return;
    }
    int mid = size/ 2;
    int leftSize = mid;
    int rightSize = size - mid;
    int[] left = new int[leftSize];
    int[] right = new int[rightSize];
    //populate left
    for(int i = 0; i < mid; i++)
    {
        mergeCount++;
        left[i] = a[i];
    }
    //populate right
    for(int i = mid; i < size; i++)
    {
        mergeCount++;
        right[i-mid] = a[i];
    }
    mergeSort(left);
    mergeSort(right);
    //merge
    merge(left, right, a);
}

public static void merge(int[] left, int[] right, int[] a)
{
    int leftSize = left.length;
    int rightSize = right.length;
    int i = 0;//index for left
    int j = 0;//index for right
    int k = 0;//index for a
    while(i < leftSize && j < rightSize)//compares until the end is reach in either 
    {
        if(left[i] <= right[j])
        {
            //assigns a[k] to left[i] and increments both i and k
            a[k] = left[i];
            i++;
            k++;
        }
        else
        {
            //assigns a[k] to right [j] and increments j  and k
            a[k] = right[j];
            j++;
            k++;
        }
    }
    //fills in the rest
    while(i<leftSize)
    {
        a[k] = left[i];
        i++;
        k++;
    }
    while(j<rightSize)
    {
        a[k] = right[j];
        j++;
        k++;
    }
}
```

Quick Sort

```
public static void quickSort(int[] a, int left, int right)
{
    int index = partition(a, left, right);
    if(left < index - 1)
    {
        //increments quickCount and calls quickSort recursively
        quickCount++;
        quickSort(a, left, index-1);    
    }
    if(index < right)
    {
        //increments quickCount and calls quicSort recursively
        quickCount++;
        quickSort(a, index, right);
    }
}
public static int partition(int[] a, int left, int right)
{
    int i = left;
    int j = right;
    int pivot = a[((left+right)/2)];
    while(i<=j)
    {
        while(a[i] < pivot)
        {
            i++;//correct position so move forward
        }
        while(a[j] > pivot)
        {
            j--;//correct position 
        }
        if(i <= j)
        {
            //swaps and increments i and decrements j
            int temp = a[i];
            a[i] = a[j];
            a[j] = temp;
            i++;
            j--;
        }
    }
    return i;
}
```

Comment: try http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

Your counts should be wherever you do a comparison of two values.

The bubbleCount should be moved up above the if because you want to count every comparison not sure the ones where the if clause is true.  The selectionCount seems okay.  The mergeCount should be moved to where you compare values.

Comment: Would I have to move the quickCount into the partition method?

Answer (score 0):

You need to count comparisons, so I would create a method to compare and count:

```
static int count;

private static boolean isGreaterThan(int i, int j) {
    count++;
    return i > j;
}
```

and always use that method to compare values:

instead of:

```
while(i<=j)
```

do:

```
while(!isGreaterThan(i, j))
```

etc